# What is best way to scale div component with fixed size inside another smaller div

Tags: css

A div component is already defined with a fixed size, which is shown in normal display mode. The div component has few nested div fixed size.

I want to show this div component as zoomed out state. The size is dynamic depends on zoom-out factor.

I don't want to change the div component size in CSS file as it is normal to display mode. What is the best way to scale the div component?

```css
.div-bird {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.div-feathers {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
}

/*zoom out. Sample zoom out size*/
.scale-bird {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bird">
  <div class="div-feathers">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scale-bird flying-bird">
  <!-- Dynamically inserted with query -->
  <div class="div-bird">
    <div class="div-feathers">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since .scale-bird is smaller than .div-bird, what is best way to scale .div-bird?

Comment: Seems like your code has some javascript usage as well. Please provide them with the code.

Comment: Javascript insert component is not important here. Thanks for remind me. I want to know what is best scale "strategy" for such use case. Javascript + css may be required to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, thats it. If I can see how the `zoom-out factor` affects the HTML, I can come up with a solution in javascript based approach. That's the only way you can scale the CSS for your requirement.

Comment: It looks like transform: scale(...); is not going to work for this case. I guess that's what I am trying to exclude. Then, JS is the easiest way. Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: .div-bird width = 200px. Container .scale-bird width = 100px. I expect: .div-bird REAL DISPLAY width = 100px (somehow scaled), which is inside container .scale-bird. In the process, no css definition is changed.

Comment: why don't you use `width:100%` to `.div-bird`

Comment: .div-bird width=200px is normal display mode. It's complicated component with too many child div with fixed size. Too complicated adjustment. If set 100%, not sure how to adjust child div (too much work). I though it would be nice not to change all div fixed size, just scale it somehow. Imaging you got component from 3rd party lib, and you don't want to spend time on div size. You just want to zoom it.

Comment: Of course, then the solution is `transform`

Comment: Can you give an example? Thank you.

Comment: I got it. Add another container div for div-bird, div-bird-container. And define: transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);